# Render without special char encoding in JS

Tags: javascript, html, char

I have the string "how are you%3F" where "%3F" represents a question mark. How can I convert it back to "?" when adding it to an HTMl element in Javascript so that it renders human readable? It needs to work for all forbidden characters eg "<" "%3C"

```
var t = document.createTextNode("how are you%3F");
```

Maybe with a reg expression?

I may just be lacking proper terminology as I can't find anything about this in searches.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
decodeURIComponent("how are you%3F");
```